# Win32 CRYTO Who is responsible for certificate permissions in CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES?

Tags: winapi, service, permissions, cryptoapi

My service use certificate in CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES.
The problem is that system makes usage of CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES very uncomfortable.
I use MMC (started as Admin) and open Local services storage for my service. Then I import certificate from file there.

I expect that newly created storage and certificate will have appropriate permissions for my service (runs under NETWORK_SERVICE). However neither storage itself, nor the private key have permissions for NETWORK_SERVICE initially.

So, my questions is: is it by design or I should avoid CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES ?